# How to find pixel coordination from world coordinates?

Tags: python, opencv, camera

I want to find pixel coordinates of my object from known world coordinate. My code finds pixel coordinate that is higher than max pixel coordinate. What is the problem on my code? I used [this matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJUqR.png) for my calculation :  This is my code in ptyhon :

```
focal_length = 1386
f_x = focal_length
f_y = focal_length
c_x = 1920/2
c_y = 1080/2


#-------------------- Find pixel

m_Rotation= np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]) # I matrix
print("\n  m_Rotation \n", m_Rotation)

m_Translation = np.array([[8, 1, 5]])
print("\n  m_Translation \n", m_Translation)

m_Transformation = np.concatenate((m_Rotation, m_Translation.T), axis=1)
print("\n  m_Transformation \n", m_Transformation)

m_target = np.array([[5], [10], [2], [1]]) 
print("\n m_target \n", m_target)

result1 = np.dot(m_Transformation, m_target) 
print("\n result1 \n", result1)

m_intrinsic = np.array([[f_x, 0, c_x], [0, f_y, c_y], [0, 0, 1]]) 
print("\n m_intrinsic \n", m_intrinsic)

result2 = np.dot(m_intrinsic, result1) 
print("\n result2 \n", result2/result2[2])
```